# Special formed box border

Tags: html, css

I need to create a html box which is not just a simple box, but it has a little tip at the bottom. I created this with HTML and CSS as you can see in the code below. First watch that.

```css
.item{
  width: 200px;
  height: 130px;
  background: gray;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  float:left;
}
.title{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 160px;
}
.tip{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid white;
}
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" style="background-image: url('http://img.dummy-image-generator.com/buildings/dummy-400x400-Window-plain.jpg')">
  <div class="title">Lorum Ipsum</div>
  <div class="tip"></div>
</div>

<div class="item" style="left:230px;">
  <div class="title">Lorum Ipsum 2</div>
  <div class="tip"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see the image in the background is also in the tip at the bottom. At the right, you seen the same but without an image and a `gray` background. But this background actually needs to be `white` with an `gray border` in the contour of the `gray` background. So also the version with the image needs this border. Below an image of what I mean.

[image]

Is it possible to create this with only HTML and CSS with support for older browsers (at least IE9). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one solution that works in old browsers; I made the border red for visibility.

```
    .item{
  width: 200px;
  height: 130px;
  background: gray;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.title{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 160px;
  border:1px solid red;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
}
.tip{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid white;
}
.tip-border{
    border-bottom-color:red;
    bottom:0;
}
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

<div class="item" style="background-image: url('http://img.dummy-image-generator.com/buildings/dummy-400x400-Window-plain.jpg')">
  <div class="title">Lorum Ipsum</div>
  <div class="tip tip-border"></div>
  <div class="tip"></div>
</div>

<div class="item" style="left:230px;">
  <div class="title">Lorum Ipsum 2</div>
  <div class="tip tip-border"></div>
  <div class="tip"></div>
</div>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/2bgdjckq/

Comment: I just put my laptop away, but on my phone I can see the red bordor at the bottom (scaled). Maybe position minus 2px?